# Object array property adds index when loading with an array

Tags: php, arrays, object

Objects are somewhat new to me.

I have an object property which is an array...  `$obj->something[]`.
I have a multidimensional associative array...  `$schedule[$year][$month][$day][$event]`.

When I load the array into the object property the object adds an index.

```
$obj->something[] = $schedule;
```

So when I pull the data out of the object I get the extra index...

```
[0][$year][$month][$day][$event]
```

I tried `array_replace` but that didn't seem to do anything.  How do I avoid getting the extra leading index?

Answer (score 1):

Assign the array directly to the property without the square brackets.

```
$obj->something = $schedule;
```

using `[]` at the end of the left-hand side of an assignment statement appends the assigned value to an array (creating the array if it doesn't exist yet).

If you have initialized the `something` property to an empty array, but it's supposed to hold your schedule array, you want `$schedule` to replace the empty array, but the way your doing it puts `$schedule` *into* that array instead.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I should have seen that but after going around in circles for so long I became scatter-brained.

Answer (score 0):

You could try array_merge. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

```
class Foo {
   private $something = [];

   function mergeEm(array $somethingElse) {
      $this->something = array_merge($this->something, $somethingElse); 
   }
}
```